# Mapping url to File System in Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat7, server.xml

I want to map the url to files located on the server, very similar to adding Aliases in httpd.conf for Apache. I dont seem to be able to find a way to do the same for Tomcat.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Referring to Mark's reply, I tried the following:

```
<Context>
    /alias/html/plugins = /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/html/plugins,/alias/html/IdaaS = /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/html/IdaaS
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
</Context>
```

referring to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Whe I hit the url  `http://someurl:8080/html/plugins`, it doesnt work, but there is such a directory

Answer (score 0):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Look for aliases. (Text to keep SO happy because it doesn't like concise answers).